# SQL Server set hours and minutes to datetime from another datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'd like to get, dynamically, hours and minutes from a date (`@datetime1`) and set them to another to a datetime (`@datetime2`):

For example :

```
@datetime1 = 2015-01-21 15:33:00
@datetime2 = 2016-03-24 19:42:00
```

Result should be :

```
@datetime2 = 2016-03-24 15:33:00
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are datetimes, you can do this with just conversions and `+`:

```
select cast(cast(@datetime1 as date) as datetime) + cast(cast(@datetime2 as time) as datetime)
```

SQL Server does allow adding together `datetime` values but not most other date/time data types.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
--@datetime1 = 2015-01-21 15:33:00
--@datetime2 = 2016-03-24 19:42:00

set @date1 = convert(date, @datetime1)
set @date2 = convert(date, @datetime2)

set @datetime3 = dateadd(second, datediff(second, @date1, @datetime1), @date2)
```

This will add the number of seconds from the day of @datetime1 to the day of @datetime2